# Using Scapy and a wireless network card to scan network - getting Network is down Error

Tags: python, networking, wifi, scapy, packet-sniffers

Disclaimer:  I can't use aircrack
I am using Ubuntu (if that helps)

I have a wireless network adapter USB device that I am using (tenda N150) to scan networks.
I have used a tutorial and in the tutorial they asked to put the device in monitor mode

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
```

The code that I am running is:

```
from scapy.all import *
from threading import Thread
import pandas
import time
import os

# initialize the networks dataframe that will contain all access points nearby
networks = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["BSSID", "SSID", "dBm_Signal", "Channel", "Crypto"])
# set the index BSSID (MAC address of the AP)
networks.set_index("BSSID", inplace=True)

def callback(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(Dot11Beacon):
        # extract the MAC address of the network
        bssid = packet[Dot11].addr2
        # get the name of it
        ssid = packet[Dot11Elt].info.decode()
        try:
            dbm_signal = packet.dBm_AntSignal
        except:
            dbm_signal = "N/A"
        # extract network stats
        stats = packet[Dot11Beacon].network_stats()
        # get the channel of the AP
        channel = stats.get("channel")
        # get the crypto
        crypto = stats.get("crypto")
        networks.loc[bssid] = (ssid, dbm_signal, channel, crypto)


def print_all():
    while True:
        os.system("clear")
        print(networks)
        time.sleep(0.5)


def change_channel():
    ch = 1
    while True:
        os.system(f"iwconfig {interface} channel {ch}")
        # switch channel from 1 to 14 each 0.5s
        ch = ch % 14 + 1
        time.sleep(0.5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # interface name, check using iwconfig
    interface = "wlxc83a35c2e0bb"
    # start the thread that prints all the networks
    printer = Thread(target=print_all)
    printer.daemon = True
    printer.start()
    # start the channel changer
    channel_changer = Thread(target=change_channel)
    channel_changer.daemon = True
    channel_changer.start()
    # start sniffing
    sniff(prn=callback, iface=interface, monitor=True)
```

The error that I am getting is:
`OSError: [Errno 100] Network is down`

This is the output of the `iwconfig`

```
wlxc83a35c2e0bb  IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Any Ideas why this might happen ?

the code that I tried it written above

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that i forgot:
`sudo iwconfig wlan0 up`
and because of that the interface stayed down.